# Stripe + TypeScript: How to extend @types/stripe definitions for stripe-node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, stripe-payments

I'm working on project, where we're using **Stripe** library for **Node**. We also want to use **TypeScript** on this project.

I've figured out that Stripe isn't providing official TypeScript definitions but I've found some community definitions [@types/stripe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/stripe) on NPM. So I installed them and after a while I got an error:
`Property 'sources' does not exist on type 'Stripe'.`

Well there are missing some definitions, for example for this [`stripe.sources`-related functionality](https://stripe.com/docs/api#sources).

I want to add missing definitions locally. So I need to extend this file:
[@types/stripe/index.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/stripe/index.d.ts)

I think that for the problem above I need:

- to add property `sources: Stripe.resources.Sources;` to class `Stripe`,
- to add class `Sources` to namespace `resources`,
- to add missing function declarations to class `Sources`.

The problem is that I really don't know how. How should the `.d.ts` file with extensions look like? I've made many attempts according some examples and TypeScript docs but it always doesn't work. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way to augment the export-assigned `Stripe` class; the problem is similar to [this open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14080) about augmenting a default-exported class.  At this time, since you can't use augmentation, you'll have to fork the `@types/stripe` definitions for your project, and then you may as well make all the desired changes that way.

Answer (score 1):

I think my colleague has found a solution that works for me. Here is how he made it:

```
import ST from 'stripe'

declare module 'stripe' {
    namespace sources {
        interface ISource extends IResourceObject {
            ...
        }

        interface ISourceCreationData {
            ...
        }
    }

    namespace resources {
        class Sources {
            create(data: sources.ISourceCreationData): Promise<sources.ISource>;
            retrieve(source: string, client_secret?: string): Promise<sources.ISource>;
        }
    }

    class Stripe extends ST {
        sources: ST.resources.Sources;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get an error that the `sources` property is missing.