# extend typing for nightmare

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, nightmare

I'm using the typings for the `nightmare` class from [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/5344bfc80508c53a23dae37b860fb0c905ff7b24/types/nightmare/index.d.ts). This is an install via npm install `@types/nightmare`

I would like to extend the existing typings without modifying the index.d.ts from node_modules. Specifically by adding the `action()` and `evaluate_now()` methods. 
`action()` is a static method.

Here is what I did
I created a custom typings file in my project root folder

**custom-typings.d.ts**

```
declare namespace Nightmare {
  export class Nightmare {
    evaluate_now<T1, T2, R>(
      fn: (arg1: T1, done: T2) => R,
      done: T2,
      arg1: T1
    ): Nightmare;
    static action<T1, T2, R>(name: string, fn: (arg1: T1, done: T2) => R): void;
  }
}
```

In my main application file, I have the following

**index.ts**

```
/// <reference path='custom-typings.d.ts'/>

import Nightmare = require('nightmare');

function size(this: Nightmare, done: any) {
  this.evaluate_now(() => {
    const w = Math.max(
      document.documentElement.clientWidth,
      window.innerWidth || 0
    );
    const h = Math.max(
      document.documentElement.clientHeight,
      window.innerHeight || 0
    );
    return {
      height: h,
      width: w
    };
  }, done);
}

Nightmare.action('size', size);

// no errors here from the types declared by the @types in node_modules.
new Nightmare()
  .goto('http://yahoo.com')
  .type('input[title="Search"]', 'github nightmare')
  .click('.searchsubmit');
```

I get the following errors

- Property 'evaluate_now' does not exist on type 'Nightmare'.
- Property 'action' does not exist on type 'typeof Nightmare'.

I'm using Typescript 3. It looks like my custom typings are not being detected. I've been pouring over the [declaration merging documents](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global namespace you declared in `custom-typings.d.ts` has nothing to do with the module.  Instead, you need to augment the module:

```
declare module "dummy" {
  module "nightmare" {
    // ...
  }
}
```

However, the `Nightmare` class is export-assigned in the original typings (`export = Nightmare`), and AFAIK export-assigned classes currently can't be augmented; see [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52323593).  So you'll have to add a modified copy of `@types/nightmare` to your project.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Isn't that issue about default export classes, and not classes exported using `export = `?

Comment: Right.  I just added a comment to the issue stating that I believe export-assigned classes have the same problem.  I don't think it would be helpful to file another issue.